# How to Add new Country In Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4.1

[image]

> How to Add new Country In Magento 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Please check below steps.

**Step1**: Open lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml

**Step2**: Locate territories tag in this file

**Step3**: copy one of territory tags for the syntax and paste it within the territories tag

**Step4**: hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you.

**Step5**: Save this file

**Step6**: Open table name directory_country

**Step7**: It has predefined syntax follow then same and create a new row and enter the same country code as entered in the en.xml file in 3 columns

**Step8**: Refresh the site’s cache.

**Step9**: Admin > Configuration > General

Thanks and Happy coding.

Comment: please check in your magento2.4.1 , did you find out lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml this directory?

Comment: Ok I will check and let you know.